# Why does validation of a line with regex work well while validation of a string fails?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to check if a users name has only Latin or Cyrillic letters and whitespaces (neither digits nor special characters). Quite obvious, so I wrote a very simple regex: `/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+$/` which does the work. But recently I read about such tricks as adding the `\n` to cheat the validation.

So I switched to: `/\A[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/` which seems to be safe, but now all the tests return `false`.

I'm checking using JavaScript and my function is:

```
stringFormat.test(login)
```

Output from Mozilla's console (to save your time):

```
stringFormat = /\A[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
/\A[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
login = "ol"
"ol"
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
stringFormat = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+$/
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+$/
validateString(login, stringFormat)
true
login = "ol345"
"ol345"
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
true
stringFormat = /\A[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
/\A[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
false
stringFormat = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+/
/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+/
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
true
login = "ol345"
"ol345"
validateString(login, stringFormat)
true
login = "345"
"345"
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
stringFormat = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+\z/
login = "ol345"
"ol345"
validateString(login, stringFormat)
false
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
false
stringFormat = /[\Aa-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s\z]+/
/[\Aa-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s\z]+/
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
true
validateString(login, stringFormat)
true
stringFormat = /\A[a-z]{5}\z/
/\A[a-z]{5}\z/
validateString("hello", stringFormat)
false
validateString("heo", stringFormat)
false
```

Could you help me out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `\A` and `\z` are not supported in JavaScript.

Just see this simple examples:

[\A[a-z]+\Z](https://regex101.com/r/y8Jlmo/1)

[^[a-z]+$](https://regex101.com/r/wKj969/1)

I suggest you to use pattern you already have, `^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]+$,` and switch off multiline mode, which will prevent `^` and `$` from matching beginning and end of a line.

[See this demo with sample pattern](https://regex101.com/r/wKj969/2)

Comment: Fortunately, I'm going to use the regexp in ruby which supports `\A` and `\z`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexanderGorg Keep in mind that Ruby's multiline mode only toggles `.` to match or not match the newline character. Ruby always uses `^` and `$` to mark the beginning and ending of a line (even with multiline mode off) and `\A` and `\z` to mark the beginning and ending of a string. For more info check the [Ruby RegExp anchors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Anchors).